# Dramatis Personae but for important words

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary, translation-check

What is a phrase that acts like Dramatis Personae (for listing the important characters of a play) but for the important words?

I've thought of Dramatis Vocabulum, but I'm sure there's a better answer to this that I just don't have the knowledge for.

Comment: I'm curious as to what you mean by 'important words'. Are these words with meanings specific to the context of the play (like invented words, or words being used in a particular sense), or do you have something more analytical in mind ('these are the key words that relate to the themes of the play', say)?

Comment: The word you want translated to latin would be 'glossary'.

Answer (score 6):

Having said that, *vocabulum* is a single vocable; it would at least be necessary to say *Dramatis vocabula*. That does in fact sound quite good. I would recommend against *dramatis verba*, which, like the English "the words of the play," is a bit too general.

In Middle Latin (= Medieval Latin) you also have *vocabularium*, which means (and is of course the root of) "vocabulary." If Middle Latin is fine, and why would it not be, I'd recommend: *Dramatis vocabularium*.

Comment: If I had a vote, I'd vote for *Dramatis vocabula*.